# How can I show the right animated text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I need to show an animated sentence in the correct translation for the user. On first start, however, flutter is as if it were loading the animation first and then looking for the right translation even though I used InitState and DidChangeDependencies. If I switch windows and return, the translation with the animation is shown correctly, only on the first start it causes problems. Here is the animation code:

```
AnimatedTextKit(
        isRepeatingAnimation: false,
         animatedTexts: [
      TypewriterAnimatedText(_frase,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 21),
      speed: Duration(milliseconds: 30))
         ])
```

This is the code of the variable "_frase":

```
    @override
      void didChangeDependencies() async {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        _frase =
            "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ext} ${DateFormat.MMMM("${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.codice}").format(DateTime.now()).capitalize()} $annoAttuale";
...
```

l10n.yaml:

```
     arb-dir: lib/traduzioni

//in the animation, the first printout makes this translation, then the correct one for the user
    template-arb-file: app_it.arb 


    output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

Comment: Can you try moving the code to set _frase inside build method? At first glance, it does seems anything wrong with your code except your didChangeDependencies is async.

Comment: The result remains the same. Performs the main translation first and then the real user translation

Comment: Did you try to print `_frase ` in your did change dependencies?

Comment: can you try creating a temp variable `final text = <translated value>` inside build method and pass it to AnimatedTextKit?

Comment: if I add "final" the animation prints an empty string, as if it didn't have time to find the right translation. In fact, doing a print first prints the sentence with the default language and then retrieves the user's one

Comment: There is something else wrong. This is side effect. How are you loading translation or setting language?

Comment: I use the "Internationalizing Flutter apps" guide, I've edited the post to show you how I set it up